# ASP.NET website is working in IIS but not in browser

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have deployed my asp.net 2.0 website on IIS, and I tested there by browsing website in IIS and it's working fine. 
But I am getting the below error while browsing the website

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns'.

Source Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <configSections>
        <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Previously when we used to create a website in IIS, it worked fine. I have checked the website folder in IIS [ By clicking Property > ASP.NET] and the framwework tageted there is 1.1, and it is in read only mode. If the problem is related to this issue than please let me know how to change it.

Comment: I'm interested to see what you mean by 'browsing website in IIS': IIS is the web server, not a browser at all -?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Property > ASP.NET` tab you need to select the 2.0 version in the version combo. If not available, it means that .NET 2.0 is not properly installed with IIS.

I had this exact error message on a machine where I installed .NET 2.0 prior to IIS.

You can fix this by opening a .NET 2.0 SDK Command Prompt, and run

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

This will register .NET 2.0 in IIS, and you will get it available in the version combo.

**NOTE:**
An alternative to run it in the SDK command prompt, is to open a standard command window and navigate to the .NET Framework 2.0 installed location and run `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` from there.
On my installation this is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50110>
```

Comment: Hi Awe,

I am facing another issue, not related to this. I have created a new thread for this, can you please check this one too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387281/class-not-registered-error-while-compiling-the-solution-in-asp-net

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting is that the attribute `xmlns` of the element `configuration` is not recognized. Before anything else, have you tried removing the `xmlns` attribute?

I've just double checked by looking at a web.config file I have to hand and the start of it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
```

i.e. No `xmlns` attribute on the `configuration` element